# Additional group by makes Postgres query incredibly slower

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to make a query that has two tables with the data I need. Below there are 3 queries. The first is the query with the first table I need. The second is the query with the second table I need. The third is the query with both tables I need.

Here are the queries I have:

```
/*Query with including the first table I need*/
set schema 'exampledata';
    select 
        count(signature),
        signature,
        example1
    from testtable
    group by  testtable.signature, testtable.example1
    order by count(signature) desc

/*Row count: 1852 rows
Query time: 2.1 secs*/


/*Query with including the second table I need*/
set schema 'exampledata';
    select 
        count(signature),
        signature,
        example2
    from testtable
    group by  testtable.signature, testtable.example2
    order by count(signature) desc

/*Row count: 1794 rows
Query time: 2.1 secs*/


/*Query with including the first and second tables I need*/
set schema 'exampledata';
    select 
        count(signature),
        signature,
        example2,
        example1
    from testtable
    group by  testtable.signature, testtable.example2, testtable.example1
    order by count(signature) desc

/*Row count: 1872 rows
Query time: 23.5 secs*/
```

Why is it that once I add one table to the query, the time it takes to process increases by tenfold? Is it because the tables do not share the same amount of rows?

Here are the explains, respectful to each query shown:

```
"Sort  (cost=151128.71..151149.41 rows=8280 width=79) (actual time=1563.842..1563.869 rows=1852 loops=1)"
"  Output: (count(signature)), signature, example1"
"  Sort Key: (count(testtable.signature)) DESC"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 316kB"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=150507.08..150589.88 rows=8280 width=79) (actual time=1563.141..1563.476 rows=1852 loops=1)"
"        Output: count(signature), signature, example1"
"        Group Key: testtable.signature, testtable.example1"
"        ->  Seq Scan on data.testtable  (cost=0.00..129087.90 rows=2855890 width=79) (actual time=0.005..618.993 rows=2807146 loops=1)"
"              Output: example14, example3, example4, example5, example1, example2, example6, example7, example8, example9, example10, example11, example12, example13"
"Planning time: 0.063 ms"
"Execution time: 1564.021 ms"



"Sort  (cost=152197.99..152249.74 rows=20700 width=85) (actual time=1584.287..1584.312 rows=1794 loops=1)"
"  Output: (count(signature)), signature, example2"
"  Sort Key: (count(testtable.signature)) DESC"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 313kB"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=150507.08..150714.08 rows=20700 width=85) (actual time=1583.538..1583.916 rows=1794 loops=1)"
"        Output: count(signature), signature, example2"
"        Group Key: testtable.signature, testtable.example2"
"        ->  Seq Scan on data.testtable  (cost=0.00..129087.90 rows=2855890 width=85) (actual time=0.005..628.403 rows=2807146 loops=1)"
"              Output: example14, example3, example4, example5, example1, example2, example6, example7, example8, example9, example10, example11, example12, example13"
"Planning time: 0.059 ms"
"Execution time: 1584.542 ms"



"Sort  (cost=794824.44..795341.94 rows=207000 width=92) (actual time=22771.282..22771.307 rows=1872 loops=1)"
"  Output: (count(signature)), signature, example2, example1"
"  Sort Key: (count(testtable.signature)) DESC"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 350kB"
"  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=728162.97..765931.60 rows=207000 width=92) (actual time=18818.703..22770.504 rows=1872 loops=1)"
"        Output: count(signature), signature, example2, example1"
"        Group Key: testtable.signature, testtable.example2, testtable.example1"
"        ->  Sort  (cost=728162.97..735302.70 rows=2855890 width=92) (actual time=18803.887..22232.128 rows=2807146 loops=1)"
"              Output: signature, example2, example1"
"              Sort Key: testtable.signature, testtable.example2, testtable.example1"
"              Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 286688kB"
"              ->  Seq Scan on data.testtable  (cost=0.00..129087.90 rows=2855890 width=92) (actual time=0.008..960.797 rows=2807146 loops=1)"
"                    Output: signature, example2, example1"
"Planning time: 0.084 ms"
"Execution time: 23085.289 ms"
```

Comment: I guess that you have `INDEX` on `signature/example1`. But when you add `example2` query optimizer has to get data directly from table. (and this costs a lot). Please provide execution plans for your queries.

Comment: I added them @lad2025

Comment: Please add the outputs of `explain (analyze, verbose)` instead of the plain `explain`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Editted `explain` to be `explain (analyze, verbose)`